# Cannot modify autoSubscribeNewMembers of Group via MS Graph

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I can successfully create a group in MS Graph. I am trying to update the `autoSubscribeNewMembers` property, but when I do I receive an error which states:
`"User does not have permissions to execute this action."`

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$groupData = @{
        displayName                 = 'TESTGROUPNAME'
        mailNickname                = 'TESTGROUPNAME'
        description                 = 'TESTGROUPNAME'
        visibility                  = 'Private'
        groupTypes                  = @('Unified')
        mailEnabled                 = $true
        securityEnabled             = $true
        "resourceBehaviorOptions"   = @("WelcomeEmailDisabled")
        "owners@odata.bind"         = @('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<USERID>')

$newGroup   = Invoke-MgGraphRequest `
    -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups' `
    -Body $groupData `
    -Method POST

$updatePayload = @{autoSubscribeNewMembers=$true}
$response   = Invoke-MgGraphRequest                                             `
    -Uri        ('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{0}' -f $newGroup.Id) `
    -Method     PATCH                                                           `
    -Body       $updatePayload                                                  `
    -OutputType HttpResponseMessage
```

At this point I get the error described.

I've confirmed that the app does have the required permissions:

[image]

Does anybody have any suggestions how I can make this work? Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Did you use `Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Group.ReadWrite.All` when connecting ?

Comment: No, I didn't. I thought that was all taken care of via the App permissions? If I assign permissions to an app, do I still need to specify that permission as a scope when connecting?

Comment: @BenjaminSelby Could you include with what account you are connecting to MgGraph? personal microsoft account or work account?

Comment: I'm connecting using a certificate which is attached to a registered app in Azure. This is my connection command:
```Connect-MgGraph  -TenantId $certificateInfo.TenantId -ClientId $certificateInfo.AppId -Certificate $certificateInfo.Cert -NoWelcome```

Comment: Ah, OK - I connected this morning using manual authentication, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As mentioned in this **[MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#:%7E:text=updating%20autoSubscribeNewMembers%2C%20support%20only%20delegated%20permissions.)**, updating **autoSubscribeNewMembers** support only **`Delegated`** permissions.

When you use **certificate-based** authentication while connecting with MS Graph, it uses **Application** type permissions (app-only access) that won't work for updating  `autoSubscribeNewMembers` .

I registered one Azure AD application and granted similar **API permissions** as below:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment by connecting MS Graph with certificate, new group created but updating  `autoSubscribeNewMembers`  property failed with **same error** as below:

```
Connect-MgGraph  -TenantId "tenantId" -ClientId "appId" -CertificateThumbprint "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -NoWelcome

$groupData = @{
        displayName                 = 'SRITESTGROUP'
        mailNickname                = 'SRITESTGROUP'
        description                 = 'SRITESTGROUP'
        visibility                  = 'Private'
        groupTypes                  = @('Unified')
        mailEnabled                 = $true
        securityEnabled             = $true
        "resourceBehaviorOptions"   = @("WelcomeEmailDisabled")
        "owners@odata.bind"         = @('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/userId')
        }

$newGroup   = Invoke-MgGraphRequest `
    -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups' `
    -Body $groupData `
    -Method POST

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

$updatePayload = @{autoSubscribeNewMembers=$true}
$response   = Invoke-MgGraphRequest                                             `
    -Uri        ('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{0}' -f $newGroup.Id) `
    -Method     PATCH                                                           `
    -Body       $updatePayload                                                  `
    -OutputType HttpResponseMessage
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, you need to use **interactive** flows to connect with MS Graph that uses `Delegated` permissions.

In my case, I ran below commands and connected to MS Graph with **delegated** access as a user:

```
Disconnect-MgGraph
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Group.ReadWrite.All
```

[image]

When I ran the code again now, **new group** created and updated `autoSubscribeNewMembers`   property successfully as below:

```
$groupData = @{
        displayName                 = 'TESTGROUPSRI'
        mailNickname                = 'TESTGROUPSRI'
        description                 = 'TESTGROUPSRI'
        visibility                  = 'Private'
        groupTypes                  = @('Unified')
        mailEnabled                 = $true
        securityEnabled             = $true
        "resourceBehaviorOptions"   = @("WelcomeEmailDisabled")
        "owners@odata.bind"         = @('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/userId')
        }

$newGroup   = Invoke-MgGraphRequest `
    -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups' `
    -Body $groupData `
    -Method POST

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

$updatePayload = @{autoSubscribeNewMembers=$true}
$response   = Invoke-MgGraphRequest                                             `
    -Uri        ('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{0}' -f $newGroup.Id) `
    -Method     PATCH                                                           `
    -Body       $updatePayload                                                  `
    -OutputType HttpResponseMessage
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I ran below command where `autoSubscribeNewMembers`   property is **true** like this:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Groups
Get-MgGroup -GroupId $newGroup.Id -Property "displayName,autoSubscribeNewMembers" | Select-Object displayName,autoSubscribeNewMembers
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the good answer. Yes, I could only get it to work with an interactive logon.